# Iphone (chrome & safari) ignore min-width

Tags: iphone, css

I just finished up the stylesheet of a website.
Then i thought of opening it up on my iphone and the design was totally screwed up. 
This is nothing new really. But normally the solution is to add a min-width to my body.

But.. this time the iphone seems to ignore it.

Can someone please tell me what i am overseeing? I'm sure there is a simple solution!

Site can be found here:

```
http://77.72.144.173/~braaaf/index.php
```

Answer (score 0):

**HTML:**

```
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no" />
</head>
```

**CSS:**

```
@media screen and (min-width: 769px)
{
    /* STYLES HERE */
}

@media screen and (min-device-width: 481px) and (max-device-width: 768px)
{ 
    /* STYLES HERE */
}

@media only screen and (max-device-width: 480px) {
    /* STYLES HERE */
}
```